# API error - Unable to load one or more of the requested types Method CommitAsync from assembly JsonApiDotNetCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, json-api

I have a basic API developed using ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework Core and JsonApiDotNetCore. When I try to execute the I am getting the following exception:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'CommitAsync' in type 'JsonApiDotNetCore.Extensions.SafeTransactionProxy' from assembly 'JsonApiDotNetCore, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here please.

My code:
Model class:

```
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Models;
using System;

namespace FF_Reports_API.Model
{
    public class Pitch : Identifiable
    {
        [Attr("id")]
        public Int64 id { get; set; }

        [Attr("pitch_name")]
        public string pitch_name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Configuration;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Controllers;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using FF_Reports_API.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using FF_Reports_API.Services;

namespace FF_Reports_API.Controllers
{
    public class PitchController : JsonApiController<Pitch>
    {

        private readonly IPitchService _pitchService;
        IConfiguration _Configuration;
        public PitchController(
            IJsonApiContext jsonApiContext,
            IResourceService<Pitch> resourceService,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            IPitchService pitchService)
            : base(jsonApiContext, resourceService, loggerFactory)
        {
            _Configuration = configuration;
            _pitchService = pitchService;
        }

        //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Pitches()
        {
            var pitches = await _pitchService.GetPitches();
            if (pitches.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(pitches);

        }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
using FF_Reports_API.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FF_Reports_API.Services
{
    public interface IPitchService
    {
        public Task<List<Pitch>> GetPitches();

    }
}
```

Service class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FF_Reports_API.Context;
using FF_Reports_API.Model;
using FF_Reports_API.Services;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FF_Reports_API.Services
{
    public class PitchService : IPitchService
    {

        readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
        public PitchService(IConfiguration configuration, AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            this._configuration = configuration;
            this._appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<Pitch>> GetPitches()
        {
            var dtPitches = new DataTable();
            var PitchesList = new List<Pitch>();
            using (var _dbContext = _appDbContext)
            {
                SqlConnection con = (SqlConnection)_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
                using (con)
                {
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("[PitchPower2].[uspGetPitches]", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        dataAdapter.Fill(dtPitches);

                    }
                    if (dtPitches.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        PitchesList = dtPitches.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(x => new Pitch
                            {
                                id = (Int64)x["id"],
                                pitch_name = (string)x["pitch_name"]

                            }).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
            return PitchesList;
        }

    }
}
```

Startup:

```
using FF_Reports_API.Context;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FF_Reports_API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

            // Add the Entity Framework Core DbContext like you normally would
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Use whatever provider you want, this is just an example
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));

            });

            // Add JsonApiDotNetCore
            services.AddJsonApi<AppDbContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AppDbContext context)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseJsonApi();
            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=PitchController}/{action=Pitches}/");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The connection string is in appsettings.json

Comment: Sound like mixing version dependencies error. Can you show the dependencies with version used by your project? (You can just add the csproj).

Comment: @vernou, thank you for looking into this. csproj code is below:`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>FF_Reports_API</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JsonApiDotNetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.17" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `JsonApiDotNetCore` at version [3.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonApiDotNetCore/3.1.0#dependencies-body-tab) depends of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` at version 2.1.0. But your project force `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` at version 5.0.17.

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 5 isn't retro-compatible with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 2.1.

You need to align the version `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` dependency between your project and `JsonApiDotNetCore`.

For this, you can downgrade `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version to 2.1. But this version isn't supported by Microsoft.

Or you can update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version to 6 and `JsonApiDotNetCore` to 5.

> None `JsonApiDotNetCore` versions support `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 5.

Comment: Thank you @vernou. After reinstalling the correct versions resolved my issue.